# Calculating the difference between values of observations in the dataset

Tags: r, difference

Imagine I have a dataset like the following:

```
| Individual | Year | x1 | x2 |
-------------------------------
|       1      |   1   |  3  |  5  |
|       1      |   2   |  7  |  4  |
|       1      |   3   |  8  |  6  | 
|       2      |   1   |  0  |  6  | 
|       2      |   2   |  9  |  2  |
```

And so on. I want to create a variable that measures the change in x1 compared to the previous year for each individual. That is I want to transform my data so it looks like:

```
| Individual | Year | x1 | x2 | Change_x1 |
---------------------------------------------
|       1      |   1   |  3  |  5  |     NA      |
|       1      |   2   |  7  |  4  |      4      |
|       1      |   3   |  8  |  6  |      1      |   
|       2      |   1   |  0  |  6  |     NA      |
|       2      |   2   |  9  |  2  |      9      |
```

So far I've tried doing this using:

```
data%>%
group_by(Individual,Year)%>%
mutate(Change_x1 = x1 - lag(x1))
```

But this only returns `Change_x1` as a column of NAs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Drop `Year` from your `group_by()` and you're good

Answer (score 0):

You do not neeed `Year` in `group_by()`

```
df %>%  
  group_by(Individual) %>% 
  mutate(Change_x1 = x1 - lag(x1))

# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Groups:   Individual [2]
  Individual  Year    x1    x2 Change_x1
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1          1     1     3     5        NA
2          1     2     7     4         4
3          1     3     8     6         1
4          2     1     0     6        NA
5          2     2     9     2         9
```